# Finding less than between months/string

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I'm needing to find the difference between two months in excel. One month is listed as a string, the other I'm calculating by doing

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"mmmmmmmmmmmm")
```

I've attempted to get values that I could then use to display a Yes/No based on it being less than. Here is what I've tried, they are on individual lines.

```
=DATEDIF(M9,G19,"YM")
=IF(M9>G19,Yes,No)
```

The DATEDIF, I was looking to find number of days, then wrap it in an IF and showing Yes/No depending on positive/negative numbers.

Comment: Your date diff returns a number value, then you are asking if one of the dates is greater than the other. How does the Yes, No tie in? What values are you looking for in the difference? Days?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare them as dates not as strings/text.

Please can you include what the month listed as a string looks like?

If you have `December` as a string in cell `A1` for example, you would convert to date using: `=DATEVALUE(1&LEFT(A1,3))`

Then get the current date with `now()`, without turning to text, and compare as dates.

Full thing: `=IF(now()>(DATEVALUE(1&LEFT(A1,3))),"Yes","No")`